# Why was it so bad for Kim Jong Nam to "visit" Japan with a fake pass?

Tags: north-korea

According the numerous news sources, Kim Jong Nam lost his "crown prince" position after he tried to visit the Tokyo Disneyland with a forged passport.

Yes, but... such things happen. Privileged elite always do such decadent things. There are regularly news that they are doing actually much more, mostly related to various earthly pleasures ([women](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kippumjo), [meal](https://www.newsweek.com/north-koreas-kim-jong-un-spends-most-his-time-eating-cheese-and-plotting-629029) line is the most known about the North Korean elite). Compared to these, a covered visit of the decadent USA culture does not seem for me so bad.

However, this little "nuance" costed for Kim Jong Nam first his "crown prince" position, and ultimately to his life<sup>1</sup>.

Why? Why was it so bad for him, while using a "pleasure squad" is okay?

<sup>1</sup><sub>He was executed not for that, but for being a [CIA informant](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2019/jun/11/kim-jong-nam-half-brother-north-korea-leader-was-cia-informant) - however, if he does not visit Disneyland, he would sit now in Kim Jong Un's seat.</sub>

Comment: I don't know the answer for sure, but I tend to imagine it's some combination of "because he got caught" and "because it directly contradicts [*Juche*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juche)."

Comment: If a person from a royal family, or is a high-ranking diplomat/government official, uses a fake ID to conceal his/her identity and got caught, is not a piece of eye-catching news, then what is news? He made N. Korea feel humiliated.

Comment: Violations of juche or humiliation or whatever excuse they give wasn't the actual problem, that's just a cover story to sell the people rather than admitting it's your standard internal politics power struggle we've seen since time immemorial.  A common facet of police states and dictatorships is that everyone has violated the law, which normally isn't a problem if you are in good political standing -- but can always be used against you as a "legal" justification for taking the person out when they are not in good standing. See also China and corruption purges.

Answer (score 6):

The DPRK is rather difficult to understand from outside (and also from inside, I presume). *Numerous news sources* have gotten it wrong numerous times.

- The *little indiscretion* might have been the pretext to justify the outcome of a power struggle. See [Gause, House of Cards, p. 55](https://www.hrnk.org/uploads/pdfs/HRNK_Gause_NKHOC_FINAL.pdf), about the factions.
- The *little indiscretion* might have been an attempt to evade the pervasive surveillance. See [Collins, Organization and Guidance Department](https://www.hrnk.org/uploads/pdfs/Collins_OGD_Web.pdf). How that applied to an adult Kim grandson in the early 2000s is hard to tell.
- Kim Jong-nam might or might not have been killed for being a *potential* figurehead of a [Chinese-sponsored](https://www.businessinsider.com/kim-jong-nam-us-intelligence-agent-malaysia-chinese-coup-overthrow-kim-jong-un-2018-1) coup, rather than any information he might have given to the CIA.

Of course I'm quoting news media and anti-DPRK NGOs here, which do have their anti-DPRK agenda ...

Comment: “Kremlin political intrigues are comparable to a bulldog fight under a rug. An outsider only hears the growling, and when he sees the bones fly out from beneath it is obvious who won.”  Winston Churchill